# Pulling random object out of array of objects

Tags: php

I have an array of objects and I'm trying to pull a random object out of it, but all I get is `id` of a single object.

```
$arrayOfItems = [];

        foreach($boxItems as $item)
        {
            if($item->getMainImage() != null)
            {
                array_push($arrayOfItems, $item);
            }
        }

        if(count($arrayOfItems)==0)
        {
            $this->fail("Theres no items with images");
        }

        $randomItem = array_rand($arrayOfItems,1);
```

Am I doing something wrong or does the array_rand just doesn't have that functionality?

Comment: need more information ! Where structure of this Class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly looking at the docs for [`array_rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) would reveal the issue, as per the description:

> array_rand — Pick one or more random keys out of an array

So the return value is a random key from the array - not the element itself.

To get the element, just use the key, perhaps like so:

```
$randomKey = array_rand($arrayOfItems, 1);
$randomItem = $arrayOfItems[$randomKey];
```